# configure package in non-standard way and resolve library requirements

Tags: configure

I am installing a package (dia-0.96.1) in non-standard way on opensuse-11 system which I don't have root access. When I start to configure the package with command:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/myusername/dia
```

I get the error: No package  'libxml-2.0' found. However I've installed in the same way `libxml2-2.9.1` package in my home directory without any error. So now when I use:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/myusername/dia --libdir=/home/myusername/libxmldir
```

I still get the same error. Is there any solution to install the package in this way?

Comment: this depends on the package, sometimes you need to pass  modified `CFLAGS` and `INCLUDES` to `./configure`.

Comment: Do you have `libxml-2.0` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: No I did not add that. Is it like including `export PATH=/pathtolibxml:${PATH}` in `~/.bashrc` file?